# Create Android application for ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

I have already an ASP.NET MVC3 application and I want to develop an Android application for it, what are the options that I have?

After some research I figured I might:

- Make a **native Android** app that uses the **controllers** in the MVC application. To use this I will need to add methods in each controller to convert the data into JSON so I can send to the Android app.
- Forget about the whole ASP.NET application and try to **connect directly to the SQL server** from the android application. I know I need to write an intermediate ASP.NET code to communicate with the database.
- Create from the MVC application a **mobile web views** and use it in the Android application. (I don't know if that is possible and how to do it).

Is any of these options valid and what other options is there? which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to could create another MVC app or area that contains controllers for data access specifically for use with the app.

I know you're using MVC3, but you might want to look at MVC4 web api for an example.

Best practice says that you should have some kind of service layer between your app and the database, so I would eliminate the second option from your list.  The other two options are viable though.

Comment: This option will be time consuming. And I've seen some awesome stuff in MVC4 but turning to it is not an option for me. If I'm to create another MVC app, how can use the same database. Do I only import the mdf file?

Comment: @Kalaji I'm not suggesting migrating to MVC4 -- I merely mentioned MVC4 web api as an example.

Comment: @Kalaji How are you connecting to the database now?  Are you using SQL Server, or attaching a db file?  If you're connecting to another SQL Server, just include the same connection string in your web.config.

Comment: @Kalaji I would recommend just creating a new area in your existing app though -- it will save you time and headache, and allow you to use the same model/data classes as your existing app.

Comment: The app was auto-generated from the ER diagram, so I guess the database is attached as .mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize either jquery mobile or [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com) (if you feel like paying for the license, it's a great product suite)  to help with developing an HTML5+Js only application that connects to data provided by your MVC project as JSON data.

Once the pure html+Js app is written, you could use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to compile it into an app for Android and iOs both.